# Multiprocessing Equally Query as pandas df then merge df's into Single df

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to summarize many tables records count, and I want it **parallelly running to save time**.

```py
list_tabl_cn =['TBL_A', 'TBL_B', 'TBL_C', 'TBL_D']

def tblRowCn(p_tbl):
    #connDb = pyodbc.connect(f'DSN={nama_db_target}', autocommit =True)
    connDb = sqlanydb.connect(uid='dba', 
                               pwd='sql',
                               host='ip:port', 
                               dbn='blah')    
    is_tableExists = ego.my_desc(p_tbl,163).shape[0] 
    if is_tableExists:
        proc_name = 'df_'+p_tbl
        if p_tbl == 'STG_CFG_SYS':
            Q_ = """\
              SELECT OPENDATE as TGL_POS, COUNT(1) CN FROM {0}
              GROUP BY TGL_POS
            """.format(p_tbl)
        else:
            Q_ = """\
              SELECT TANGGAL_POSISI as TGL_POS, COUNT(1) CN FROM {0}
              GROUP BY TGL_POS
            """.format(p_tbl)
        df_tbl = pd.read_sql_query(Q_, connDb, parse_dates=['TGL_POS'])
        df_tbl['THN'],df_tbl['BLN']= df_tbl['TGL_POS'].dt.year, df_tbl['TGL_POS'].dt.month    
    else:
        df_tbl=[]

    return df_tbl

def task(table_nm):
    print(f"Task Executed with process {mp.current_process().pid}")
    tblRowCn(table_nm.upper())

def main():
    executor = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()-8)
    executor.map(task, [n_table_nm for n_table_nm in list_tabl_cn])
    executor.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

May be something like this

```py
def main():
    executor = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()-8)
    executor.map(task, [n_table_nm for n_table_nm in list_tabl_cn])
    append.[task1, task2, task...]   
    executor.close()
```

Which my whole dataframe is `append.[task1, task2, task...]`

I believe I missed something in my code, but it is too blur.

Answer (score 0):

If all your `Dataframes` has same columns and you want all the rows of all dataframes to be added in to one `dataframe`, then you can use pandas `concat` function. add all your individual dataframes to a list, then concat all of them to make your main dataframe.

```
list_of_df =[] 
for df in executor.map(task, list_tabl_cn):
    if df:
        list_of_df.append(df)
main_df = pd.concat(list_of_df)
```

you can remove the else condition in `tblRowCn` method, its redundant and not needed.

In your code you generated a list from `list_tabl_cn` to pass it to map function, you don't have to do that, you can give `list_tabl_cn` to map function directly as in the above code.

Comment: Somehow, the processes were trapped within exception and I got `error` as follow:

```python
Task Executed with process 1008
Task Executed with process 1009
Task Executed with process 1010
Task Executed with process 1011
Exception within: (b'Failed to initialize connection object', -1)
```

Comment: This might be related to your DB connection, did you check if there is any issue in creating your db connection?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Try debugging your code and see what causing this error. Without knowing issue I can't help.